# Career development as remote employee?

Tags: career-development, politics, training

I am doing remote account management for a US based company.
I do a little bit of everything, including presales and support.
Right now the company is getting more structured, hiring a crapload of senior managers.

I asked for some career development plan and some "training roadmap" for my next role. My manager told me to "you are doing great, keep learning from others through your [remote] interactions".

So, no structured role at a time when the company is getting structured AND hiring people with 10-20 years of experience.

I think that if I had a more defined role I could have more job security, as opposed to a random manager saying "hey who is this random guy? I need a specific team, let's cut the costs and bring in my buddies".

How can I establish my own role, defending myself from upcoming cliques, as a remote employee?

Comment: Do you exist on the company's organisational chart? Do you have a title? That means you have a clear place in the company. How frequently are you checking in with your achievements, or participating in conversations and meetings remotely? That means you have a presence.